# send_keys elementNotInteractableException エラー

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Pythonのseleniumについての質問です。

社内web なので、ウェブサイトを記載する事ができないことをご了承ください。
Webサイトのイメージは、こんな感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Google Chromeで特定のサイトに移動し、`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='aaa']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]").click`
で要素をクリックまでエラーなく実行出来ました。（実際にクリックできているかは分かりません）
上記画像でいう、『りんご』をクリックしています。

その後ウェブサイトを少しスクロールしたいので
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='aaa']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`
でスクロールしようと思ったのですが、`ElementNotInteractableException` とエラーが表示されスクロールできませんでした。

なにか解決できそうなアドバイスなどありましたら試してみるので、何でもご教示ください。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Python のコードも含まれていた方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[selenium-webdriver - Pythonを使ったスクロール | selenium-webdriver Tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/ja/selenium-webdriver/example/28140/python%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH to chromedriver.exe')
> driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/')
> target = driver.find_element_by_link_text('BROWSE TEMPLATES')
> actions = ActionChains(driver)
> actions.move_to_element(target)
> actions.perform()
> ```

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH to chromedriver.exe')
> driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/')
> target = driver.find_element_by_link_text('BROWSE TEMPLATES')
> driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', target)
> ```

Comment: 完璧ですね。おかげで解決しました。ありがとうございました！